# Can a site have an A/B test?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, testing, site-name

Health SE has an discussion about the name. In short, most of the mods agree that `Health` is not a good name, but there is no consensus for the replacement. In my opinion, there is no fact-based but only opinion-based. A good test will answer them all.

Can a site have an [A/B test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing)?

Link:

- [I think the reason the site attracts personal questions is because of its name](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/407/99) (Meta post)
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28979/about-the-name-of-the-site (chat)

Comment: You mean different users will see different site name, randomly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In theory, sure.

In practice, there are several issues with this. Not to mention that this would require a ton of development work, meaningfully A/B testing a site name is practically impossible:

- What would you measure? Presumably the number of off-topic questions asked and how that differs in the A and B group. Health.SE currently gets 3.4 questions per day, but you need a huge amount of data points for an A/B test's result to have any sort of significance. This test would run forever before any meaningful conclusions even have a chance of being made.
- Even if you A/B test everything that's displayed on the site itself, the site doesn't live in isolation. What about data in the API, used by mobile apps etc.? What about things displayed in the "hot questions" list, the "other accounts" lists on profile pages on various other Stack Exchange sites? And finally what about things that are completely outside our control? Links on blogs, Twitter, Facebook, other websites?
- And most notably, what about Google? We can't make Google take part in the A/B test, to display "health" to people in the A group and "medical" to people in the B group. Results would be skewed heavily to whatever group GoogleBot is in. And it wouldn't even be only about what Google *displays* – their search algorithms would have to account for the distinction whether a user is in the A or B group and perform different searches. Without Google being part of the test, but with half the site's traffic coming from Google, nothing meaningful will come out of it.

A/B testing works well for testing small, isolated changes, but not for something huge and all-encompassing like the site's name.

Comment: If the mods decide to have the test with something "small, isolated changes, but not for something huge and all-encompassing like the site's name", then can the site have that test?

Comment: If you can make a good case for it, it's possible, but setting up any A/B test is a decent amount of work. You have to do the dev work to support both alternatives, you have to ensure that the test is set up correctly to be stastically valid and significant, you may have to change caching rules, you have to constantly monitor the test to be sure it's performing correctly, etc. That amount of work has to be justified, and the justification has to be more than "We're curious about X".

Answer (score -1):

Just create two community wiki answers.

The one should say with big letters 'keep health' the other 'change to medical'.

Then ask people to upvote the answers. That will probably work.

Comment: This might get closed and deleted, many users and some SE employees are against any kind of poll in meta sites. :/